# RandomForest in R linear regression tails mtry

Tags: r, statistics, regression, random-forest

I am using the randomForest package in R (R version 2.13.1, randomForest version 4.6-2) for regression and noticed a significant bias in my results: the prediction error is dependent on the value of the response variable. High values are under predicted and low values are over predicted. At first I suspected this was a consequence of my data but the following simple example shows that this is inherent to the random forest algorithm:

```
n = 50; 
x1 = seq(1,n) 
x2 = matrix(1, n, 1)
predictors = data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2)
response = x2 + x1
rf = randomForest(x=predictors, y=response)
plot(x1, response)
lines(x1, predict(rf, predictors), col="red")
```

No doubt tree methods have their limitations when it comes to linearity but even the simplest regression tree, e.g. tree() in R, does not exhibit this bias. I can't imagine that the community would be unaware of this but haven't found any mention, how is it generally corrected for? Thanks for any comments

EDIT: The example for this question is flawed, please see "RandomForest for regression in R - response distribution dependent bias" at stack exchange for an improved treatment https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28732/randomforest-for-regression-in-r-response-distribution-dependent-bias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've discovered isn't an inherent bias in random forests, but simply a failure to properly adjust the tuning parameters on the model.

Using your example data:

```
rf = randomForest(x=predictors, y=response,mtry = 2,nodesize = 1)
plot(x1, response)
lines(x1, predict(rf, predictors), col="red")
```

[image]

For your real data the improvement will be unlikely to be so stark, of course, and I'd bet you'll get more mileage out of `nodesize` than `mtry` (`mtry` did most of the work here).

The reason that regular trees didn't exhibit this "bias" is because they, by default, search over all variables for the best split.

Comment: thank you Joran. Something didn't feel right and I am glad to see there is a solution.  Unfortunately for my work, I have already tuned the parameters with little effect (except of course nTrees) and so I mostly ignored them for this "simple" example - I guess the bias truly does exist in my case, thanks again

Comment: Fair enough...though if it's limited to your data, it isn't really a bias in RFs, is it? ;) You just have some hard to model data!

Comment: yup, the bias in RF is avoidable - I've changed the title of this question so that it may be more helpful to people in the future